# How to insert events into Google Calendar API by using PHP?

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client, google-calendar-api

I have some problem to understand the google calendar API. I want to insert my event to my diary. But it doesn't work. My agenda should be in "public" ?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MASTERSINGE THE BEST");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MyDevelopperKey");
$client->setClientId('MyIdClient ');
$client->setClientSecret('MySecret');
$client->setAccessType('offline');// Gets us our refreshtoken
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.read'));

$googleApievent = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$googleApievent->setSummary('My event');
$googleApievent->setLocation('Paris éào');

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDate('2017-02-16');
$start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$start->setDate('2017-02-16');

$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDate('2017-02-17');
$end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$end->setDate('2017-02-17');

$googleApievent->setStart($start);
$googleApievent->setEnd($end); 

$attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('myemail'); 
$attendees = array($attendee1 
);
$googleApievent->attendees = $attendees;      

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $googleApievent);/
echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or output?

Comment: Yes I have 2 errors : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message ' in /var/www/html/mysite/www/vendors/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118     && Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }

Comment: So you probably have to login / authorize yourself first in order to insert events.

Comment: How can I authorize  lyself to insert events ?

Comment: You can read up on that [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my line : $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.read')); but I have the same errors :(

Comment: there seems to be quite a lot missing from your code as compared to the worked example: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php I suggest you work through that before you go any further. And make sure you've completed all the pre-requisite steps before you test your code.

Answer (score 0):

My code is little bit longer, can we optimize ?
I am not sure if my token will refresh after 1 hours  :x   It is possible to use Google Calendar API without asking authentification ?

```
 <?php
       public function calendarAction()
        {
            define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'RK THE BEST');
            define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', __DIR__ . '/credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
            define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
        define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
                \Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
        ));

        /**
         * Returns an authorized API client.
         * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
         */
        function getClient()
        {
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
            $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
            $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");


            // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
            $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

            if(file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
                $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);

                echo "WIN :)";

                if (isset($_GET['code'])){

                    $credentials = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
                    $code = trim($_GET['code']);
                    $authCode = $code;
                    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


                    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
                    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                        // save refresh token to some variable
                        $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();

                        // update access token
                        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);

                        // pass access token to some variable
                        $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();

                        // append refresh token
                        $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

                        // save to file
                        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessTokenUpdated));
                    }

                        // Service creation
                        $service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

                        $googleApievent = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
                        $googleApievent->setSummary('google api');
                        $googleApievent->setLocation('google api');

                        $start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $start->setDate('2017-02-20');
                        $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
                        $start->setDate('2017-02-20');

                        $end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $end->setDate('2017-02-17');
                        $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
                        $end->setDate('2017-02-17');

                        $googleApievent->setStart($start);
                        $googleApievent->setEnd($end);

                        $calendarId = "primary";

                        $createdEvent = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $googleApievent);
                        echo $createdEvent->getId();         

                       while (true) {
                            foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
                                echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary() . "\n";
                                // get events
                                $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);

                                foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
                                    echo "<br/>" . $event->getSummary() . "";
                                    echo " ID : " . $event->getId() . "<br/>";
                                    echo "***********************" . "<br/> ";
                                }
                            }
                            $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();

                            if ($pageToken) {
                                $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
                                $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }

            }else {

                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n<a href='%s' > ici </a>\n",  $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';

                /****TOKEN***********************/
                if(!empty($_GET['code'])) {
                    $code = trim($_GET['code']);
                    $authCode = $code;

                    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

                    // Store the credentials to disk.
                    if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
                        mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
                    }

                    $token = $client->getAccessToken();

                    if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){  // if token expired
                        // refresh the token
                        $test=$client->refreshToken($token);

                    }
                    $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
                    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
                    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
                    $client->authenticate($code);


                    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
                        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
                        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                    }


                    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
                        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
                        print "LogOut";
                        $service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

                        $googleApievent = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
                        $googleApievent->setSummary('wake up');
                        $googleApievent->setLocation('wake up');

                        $start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $start->setDate('2017-02-16');
                        $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
                        $start->setDate('2017-02-16');

                        $end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
                        $end->setDate('2017-02-17');
                        $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
                        $end->setDate('2017-02-17');

                        $googleApievent->setStart($start);
                        $googleApievent->setEnd($end);

                        $calendarId = "primary";

                        $createdEvent = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $googleApievent);
                        echo $createdEvent->getId();                  


                        while (true) {
                            foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
                                echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary() . "\n";
                                // get events
                                $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);

                                foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
                                    echo "<br/>" . $event->getSummary() . "";
                                    echo " ID : " . $event->getId() . "<br/>";
                                    echo "***********************" . "<br/> ";
                                }
                            }
                            $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();

                            if ($pageToken) {
                                $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
                                $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                return $client;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use Google Calendar Api with service account, and it's work well !!!

```
session_start();
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' .get_include_path().'/yourPath/client_secret.json');
    define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
            Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
    ));

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setApplicationName("MasterSinge");

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

    $googleApievent = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $googleApievent->setSummary('TEST!!!!!!!!!!!');
    $googleApievent->setDescription('TEST : <b>Bloublou !!!!!!!!!!!</b>'); /*ajout d'un lien*/
    $googleApievent->setLocation('TEST !!!!!!!!!!!');

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDate('2017-02-23');
    $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $start->setDate('2017-02-23');

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDate('2017-02-23');
    $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $end->setDate('2017-02-23');

    $googleApievent->setStart($start);
    $googleApievent->setEnd($end);

    $calendarId = "yourGmailAdresse@gmail.com";

    $createdEvent = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $googleApievent);
    echo $createdEvent->getId();


    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
            echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary() . "\n";
            // get events
            $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);



            foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
                echo "<br/>" . $event->getSummary() . "";
                echo " ID : " . $event->getId() . "<br/>";
                echo "***********************" . "<br/> ";
            }
        }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
```